# What are the recommended prefix naming conventions for components in Flex 3?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, naming-conventions

I'm looking for a standard way to name components in my Flex application.  For example, all TextFields begin with "txt" in their ID attribute (i.e., "txtFirstName").  Rather than re-invent the wheel, is anyone familiar with a list of prefix naming conventions that I can use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no prefix convention that Adobe recommends since they use the full name of the component in a component instance name.

For instance: usernameTextInput, userComboBox, etc.

> If you want to incorporate the type into the name, make it the last “word”. Don't use the old ActionScript 1 convention of concatenating abbreviated type suffixes such as _mc to indicate type. For example, name a border Shape border, borderSkin, or borderShape, but not border_mc.

More info: http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Coding+Conventions#CodingConventions-Naming

If you really want to use prefixes, you might want to use the VB prefixes: http://www.rwc.uc.edu/cook/VBI_PREFIXES.HTM

Answer (score 1):

Check out Adobe's [Flex Coding Conventions](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Coding+Conventions) document.  Most of the flex code you see stays pretty true to this coding standard.